# File access permission denied even after setting ACL in linux

Tags: linux, shell, permissions, permission-denied

I've set ACL for an svn folder as follows

```
# file: www
# owner: aks
# group: users
user::rwx
group::rwx    
group:users:rwx
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

but despite this, when another user does an svn up, he gets

```
svn: Can't open file 'www/.svn/lock': Permission denied
```

What am i missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of a lock file requires *write access* to said lock file.

Assuming that you are using the same ACL for the lock file as well (you have listed the ACL for the parent folder instead), your ACL does not allow any user except for the owner to write to that file.

From the [`acl(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/acl):

> The ACL_MASK entry denotes the maximum access rights that can be granted by entries of type ACL_USER, ACL_GROUP_OBJ, or ACL_GROUP.

In essence, the ACL mask affects all named user entries and all group entries - in your case that removes write access from the `users` group that I assume contains the user that runs `svn`.